# Calculating the dot product of matrix A and B and setting the entry in matrix C[i][j] in x-86

Tags: function, x86, x86-64, matrix-multiplication, dot-product

I already have a function that calculates the dot product of the corresponding row and column in matrices A and B and returns the value, which I then call the function mod on (to avoid overflow errors). I am now trying to set the corresponding entry C[i][j] in the matrix C, which is passed in as a base pointer to an empty matrix.

I think that my code handles every thing correctly and preserves the function call protocol, yet I get a segmentation fault as a result of the line mov %rax, (%rdx) which is where I am trying to store the correct value into the location in matrix C. I do not understand why this produces a seg fault. Is there some other way to store a value into a specific location in matrix C?

Here is my code

```
.globl matrix_prod
matrix_prod:            # void matrix_prod(void *A, void *B, void *C, int n);
                               # rdi - A  rsi - B  rdx - C  rcx - n

mov $0, %r10    #set i to 0
mov $0, %r11      #set j to 0


outerloop:
cmp %rcx, %r10      
jge endloop #i<n-1

innerloop:
cmp %rcx, %r11 
jge innerloopdone   #j<n-1

push %rdx   #store C on stack
push %rcx   #store n on stack
push %r10  #preserve i during function call
push %r11  #preserve j during function call

mov %rcx, %rdx   #move n into rdx for dot prod
mov %r10, %rcx   #move i into rcx for dot_prod
mov %r11, %r8    #move j into r8 for dot_prod

call dot_prod       #long dot_prod(void *A, void *B, int n, int i, int j)
                                   # rdi     rsi      rdx    rcx    r8
pop %r11
pop %r10
pop %rcx
pop %rdx

push %rsi  #store B on stack
push %rdi  #store A on stack

mov %rax, %rdi  #mov return value from dot_prod into rdi for mod
mov $17, %rsi    #mov 17 into rsi for mod

call mod    # unsigned char mod(long x, unsigned char m);
                                 #rdi     rsi

pop %rdi  #restore A value after mod
pop %rsi  #restore B value after mod

push %rdx
push %rcx

#calculate C[i][j] = C+(i*n)+j

imul %r10, %rcx   #rcx now holds i*n
add %r11, %rcx    #cx now holds (i*n)+j
add %rcx, %rdx    #rdx now holds address for C+(i*n)+j


#mov result from mod into location C[i][j]
mov %rax, (%rdx)  #creates seg fault

pop %rcx
pop %rdx

inc %r11  #j++
jmp innerloop

innerloopdone:
incq %r10  #i++
jmp outerloop   


endloop:


ret
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see if it segfaults the first time, or only after incrementing.  And to see what value `%rdx` actually holds.  (BTW, you don't actually need to multiply in the loop, just add `n` every iteration of the outer loop.)  Use `gdb`'s `layout reg` to watch register values as you single-step.

Comment: Are you sure that mod doesn't change rdx? I bet it does.